# Independent or dependent samples?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, mean, group-differences

I have the data given below for 8 weeks for 2 different variables measured on the same scale (0-10) - and the data is only for the same subject, i.e. the person is measured 8 times on both variables once in week for the period on 8 weeks:

[image]

My question is, in order to test the mean difference of **var 1** and **var 2**, is it now the case of independent or dependent samples? - Which type on (t-test) is correct for this scenario?

UPDATE:
Actually, in addition to the previous information the week period will be longer in reality because the data gathering will continue in time. Also, the nature of var1 and var2 are psychological and medical variables: the one measures mood and the other measure some physical symptom like headache.

Comment: Looks like a classical case for a dependent t-test.

Comment: Do you believe that the scores on var1 and var2 can be meaningfully compared, i.e., that the null hypothesis that means are equal makes sense? I mean, personally I wouldn't feel able to compare my mood and my headache on any meaningful scale.

Comment: Lewian, very understandable question. There is a motivation to measure wheatear mood and headache (both measured on the same scale, 0-10) are at equal mean level, along with their correlative relationship. The correlative relationship is the first hand information, but also the mean level of difference is good to be taken into consideration as for the interpretation of the results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all data are from the same person, one would normally think of all data as being dependent of all others. No standard test can handle such a situation, as your effective sample size is 1 (only one person involved), so there is no way to assess random variation.

Technically one could make independence assumptions anyway, for example one could assume that all weeks are independent of each other and run a t-test for dependent observations with sample size 8 to compare the two variables. However it seems hard to argue on what basis the weeks should be seen as independent. Another possible approach would be to set up a time series model for the 8 weeks that somehow allows you to test whether the two variables' distributions only differ by random variation (optimally having more than 8 weeks of data; 8 time points don't allow much model diagnostic; such diagnostic could even hint at the weeks behaving as if they were independent by the way). None of this however can be justified without proper knowledge of the meaning and background of the observations.

Comment: That is, indeed, valuable pondering around the issue. I will add some further info into the question body to see, if it help a bit more.

Comment: Fair enough. Unfortunately this doesn't make me believe that the weeks could be treated as independent, or that 8 observations are enough to set up a meaningful time series model. (Although I don't exclude the possibility that in principle really detailed understanding of the data and their background would allow some realistic assumptions that could be made here.)